# Ember.js Multiple Selection on Click -- Dropdown Menu

Tags: ember.js

New to ember but trying to figure out how to allow selections on click. Once selected, I want to have the ability to select 'Remove' from the actions dropdown to remove the images from the store. Is this possible or do I have to revert to a checkbox somewhere?

[Gist Here](https://gist.github.com/al3x-edge/9233314)

[JSBin Here](http://jsbin.com/pezikuji/1/edit)

Comment: Mind converting that to a jsbin for easier editing?

Comment: Added JSbin to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out: http://jsbin.com/pezikuji/2/

What I've basically done in this update was bind a property called "isSelected" from your model to your view.

I'm then using that property in ImagesController to create a computed property called canDelete. This is used by the template in an if statement to show/hide a menu item.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Very cool, but instead when items are selected, what would be the best way to remove multiples using the remove button based on what was selected?

Comment: The thing to do in this case is attach an action to the remove menu item. The action is then defined in the controller's action hash. You can then use the same method that filters isSelected on your array to trigger a remove. You already have that in the jsbin, you just need to implement the behavior.